# Uploading Excel sheet in php to db give only last row

Tags: php, mysql

I tried uploading an excel sheet (csv) to my db in php but it indicates successful. But wen I go to the mysql to confirm, I notice only the last row in the excel sheet is showing in the mysql table. please need help. I dont know what else to do.

```
<?php
include ("base.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //inserting into db
    //getting the file and inserting it in db
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $tot = 0;
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {

            //only run if the first column if not equal to name
            if ($data[0] != 'name') {

                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[0]);
                $reg_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[1]);
                $lab = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[2]);
                $test = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[3]);
                $exam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[4]);
                $total = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[5]); 
                $grade = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[6]);
                $remark = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[7]);

                //inserting into db
                $sql = "INSERT INTO imt303 (name, reg_no, lab, test, exam, total, grade, remark) 
                        VALUES ('$name', '$reg_no', '$lab', '$test', '$exam', '$total', '$grade', '$remark')"; 
            }

        //incrementing    
        $tot++;
        }
    }

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Uploaded Successfully!");</script>';
    } else {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("There is a problem uploading file!");</script>';
    }
}

?>

<html>

<form method="POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: you could use load data infile.

Comment: Do you understand that on each `while` iteration you __overwrite__ `$sql`?

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` shoud be in loop body

Comment: Two questions.  1) Whats the `$tot` for, your not using it in the code. 2) Doesn't the for loop only loop once as you start at 0 and loop to less then 1?

Comment: @u_mulder how do correct it

Comment: @cske how? tell me more

Comment: Thanks guys. It worked. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting $sql value. The $sql value is the last value assigned leading to one query. Either you include the query inside the while loop (not recomanded) or you create an array of $sql[] that you iterate and insert or the last form I would do, create a main $sql with insert value and concatenate the values in loop making one big insert.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Works perfectly now